# Cloud formation security group is not creating ingress rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created a cloudformation template for a security group with 3 ingress rules, one for SSH, one for HTTP, and another one for HTTP(port8080)

First things first, when I include SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId, the group does not create at all. When I remove this, the group creates but only with one rule (the ssh rule).

Here is the full template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Provision security group to allow SSH access to instance
Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that will be prefixed to resource names
    Type: String
  SSHLocation:
    Description: The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: '(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})'
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.

Resources:
  InstanceSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      VpcId: !ImportValue hvfVPC-Name
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access and HTTP from the load balancer only
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref SSHLocation
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId: !ImportValue wordpressELB-SG-Id
          SourceSecurityGroupName: !ImportValue wordpressELB-SG-Name
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '8080'
          ToPort: '8080'
          SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId: !ImportValue wordpressELB-SG-Id
          SourceSecurityGroupName: !ImportValue wordpressELB-SG-Name
```

This ends up just running for a long time without actually creating the group. When I remove both SourceSecurityGroupId and SourceSecurityGroupName, the template runs, however it only creates one ingress rule.

I have triple checked to make sure the exports are correct, they are, but for some reason unless I remove those two lines, Cloudformation just hangs

Pictures attached for clarification
[CloudFormation says the group is created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOnR7.png)
[Only the SSH ingress rule is actually created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hHRU.png)

[Exports from the ELB template that I'm trying to use in the SG template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cFpJ.png)

Comment: The WordPress ELB security group is in a different AWS account to this stack?

Comment: Why are you specifying `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId`?

Comment: No, the ELB is on the same account, I posted a picture of the exports from it
According to the documentation you have to specify the ID when using a non-default VPC

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should simply specify `SourceSecurityGroupId` instead of `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` and `SourceSecurityGroupName`. Something along the lines:

```
    - IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 80
      ToPort: 80
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue wordpressELB-SG-Id
```

Similar configuration happily works for me.

The documentation on [`SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule-1.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-rule-sourcesecuritygroupownerid) says:

> You can't specify this parameter in combination with the following parameters: the CIDR IP address range, the IP protocol, the start of the port range, and the end of the port range.

Which might be the reason for the rule to not being created.

Next, it seems you were specifying the ID of the source security group `wordpressELB-SG-Id` in `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId`. `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` is actually the AWS *account ID* for the source security group, so this was not correct anyway.

Comment: Are you saying that I can't specify the Source group ID along with the CIDR from the rule above? 

that actually makes a bit of sense, let me try that out and I'll get back and mark this as answered if that works

Comment: @jhax No, I'm not saying that. You can specify `SourceSecurityGroupId` along with CIDR etc. I'm quoting AWS docs which are saying you can't specify `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` in combination with the CIDR IP address range, the IP protocol, the start of the port range, and the end of the port range. `SourceSecurityGroupId` and `SourceSecurityGroupOwnerId` are different things.